# why I can't install java jdk on mac?

Tags: java, ios, android-studio

i have installed android studio , i want to test hello world on emulator , but its saying building process has failt , i try to figure out where is the problem ,i found that on terminal its saying there is no jdk installed :
[image]

on my mac's system preferences its showing there is java :
[image]

on my android studio i found a strange path of jdk , as it seems to me , may be it is normal path , correct me please:

[image]

the problem is that when i download jdk from oracle , once i click on icon to start installation , it doesn't , i am clicking , its not installing and its not showing any errors , Could you give me some help on that issue

Answer (score -1):

> **Android studio comes with a builtin jdk in it** but it is not recommended to use an external jdk in the operating system's environment variable! attached to your android studio especially in OSX! I never needed oracle's jdk for android!

in **apple's mac OSX there is already a very basic java installed** that comes builtin in the operating system in it. if you want to install oracle java you have to first download the java SE for OSX 64bit and then

follow the instructions here

[how to install Oracle java in OSX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html)

after installing it you will get a path some what like this

> /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_06 --exec javac -version

**after that you have to manually set that path in your android studio settings for jdk** 
and there you go you will be using latest jdk by oracle in android studio

Comment: thanks rizwan , i have already downloaded jdk  , but its not instaling after clicking on the icon and uts not showing any error

Comment: that's odd! have you tried restarting the system or force quitting operations already running on OS and then retrying to install?

Comment: yes in fact 2 times i have forced my mac to turn off while was android studio still opened and restarted my machine again by the way i downloaded sublime text to see if it will happen this issue of instalation , but it didn't, installation was very normal with sublime